# Chartkick gem, trying to create a pie chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I just installed the `gem "chartkick"` to my gemfile and copyied and pasted some code just to get the project started, this is what I used in my view.

```
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
```

I also included

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "path/to/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
```

So that is not the issue but I keep getting this error

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, After installing the **"chartkick" gem,**

replace this javascript include tag

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "path/to/highcharts.js", "chartkick" %>
```

with this

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
```

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. Still same error message.

Comment: @CameronBass: try to add this <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>  in your subscribed_num.html.erb and restart the server, then rerun it.